# Convert ASPX files to XML or RSS for Wordpress

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wordpress

Is any possibility how can i convert simple ASPX files to XML file?
I need to convert cca 300 files and import them to Wordpress, but i´m .NET beginner.

Comment: Why would you like do do that? Aspx is quite close to HTML (except for the controls), do you want to have a rendered version of or pages in WP? 
Try explaining yourself better and we can try to help you :-)

Comment: Does the ASPX encoded with XML?  Can you post a sample of ASPX file?

Comment: Wordpress may be giving errors when trying to import an ASPX and it won't give errors when converted to XML.

Answer (score 0):

It´s for my client, so i need to do that by this way.
I need as an output only 1 XML/RSS file for import articles to Wordpress.

ASPX files look like this:

```
    <%@ Page Title="Megújulnak az oktatás alapjai a Debreceni Egyetemen" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/hun/news/news.master" %>

<asp:content contentplaceholderid="cphHead" runat="Server">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Megújulnak az oktatás alapjai a Debreceni Egyetemen" />
    <meta name="description" content="A felhő alapú levelezést és az Office 365 szolgáltatásait minden debreceni egyetemista ingyenesen veheti igénybe a Oktatási Alapcsomagjának köszönhetően." />
    <style type="text/css">
        img.itfimg {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:content>
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="cphContent" runat="Server">
    <h1>Megújulnak az oktatás alapjai a Debreceni Egyetemen</h1>
    <p><b>A felhő alapú levelezést és az Office 365 szolgáltatásait minden debreceni egyetemista ingyenesen veheti igénybe a  Digitális Oktatási Alapcsomagjának köszönhetően.</b></p>
    <p>A világszinten is a legmodernebbek közé tartozó szolgáltatást a Debreceni Egyetem meglévő hallgatói már használhatják, az idén felvettek pedig a beiratkozáskor kapnak olyan egyedi e-mail címet, amelynek a vége az oktatási intézményre utal, ily módon is erősítve az egyetemi közösséghez tartozást. </p>
    <p>Az egyetem és a szoftvercég együttműködése a jövőben tovább folytatódik: a Microsoft szakemberei képzéseket tartanak majd az egyetemen, így a hallgatók ingyenesen megtanulhatják a most bevezetett technológiák használatát, s azt, hogyan használhatják a felhő alapú alkalmazásokat a tanulás során és a nemzetközi tudományos életben. A Microsoft Magyarország az ország több más egyetemével működik együtt, és tervez hasonló, innovatív együttműködést. </p>
    <%--<p><i><b>A Digitális Oktatási Alapcsomagról:</b></i><br />
     &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Magyarország és a Microsoft Magyarország sikeres együttműködésének eredményeként 2012-től még hatékonyabb tanulási és tanítási környezet válik elérhetővé hazánk oktatási intézményeinek részére. A  felajánlásaként minden köz- és felsõoktatási intézmény ingyenes igényelheti az úgynevezett Digitális Oktatási Alapcsomagot. A megoldáscsomag része – többek között – az intézményi és diáklevelezés, a csoportmunka, az intranet, vagy éppen az előadás-sugárzási és videokonferencia-lehetőség is. <br /> 
     &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;A Digitális Oktatási Alapcsomag által kínált korszerű tanulási környezetet a diákok és hallgatók az iskolán kívülről, otthonról is elérhetik. Ennek köszönhetően a jövő nemzedéke már a tanulmányai során közvetlen tapasztalatot szerezhet arról, mit jelent a távoli munkavégzés, a coworking és a mobilitás egy olyan korban, ahol az ún. felhő-alapú szolgáltatások alapvetően változtatják meg az emberek viszonyát a munkaidő, vagy a fizikai értelemben vett munkahely fogalmaihoz.
    </p>   
        <p><i><b>A ról:</b></i><br />
     &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;A  a világ legnagyobb számítástechnikai eszközszállító és szolgáltató cége. Széles termékválasztéka az operációs rendszerektől és alkalmazásoktól kezdve a felhőalapú lakossági és vállalati szolgáltatásokon át az összetett hálózati, üzleti szoftverekig terjed. A céget William H. Gates és Paul G. Allen alapította 1975-ben. Mára a világ több mint 90 országában van jelen, dolgozóinak száma pedig meghaladja a 80 000 főt.<br /> 
     &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;A  Magyarország 1993-ban alakult, mindössze 2 fővel. Dolgozóinak létszáma jelenleg megközelíti a 200 főt, partnerprogramjában pedig 2200 hazai vállalkozással működik együtt. A magyar leányvállalat 2003-ban, 2006-ban, 2008-ban, valamint 2012-ben is elnyerte a „Legjobb Munkahely” címet, 2010-ben pedig az MNKSZ pályázatán a “Legjobb Női Munkahely 2009” címet érdemelte ki. A  Magyarország a 2012-2013-as üzleti évben a világ összes  leányvállalata közül a legjobbnak bizonyult. A magyar leányvállalat ügyvezetői igazgatói posztját 2011. október 24-től Papp István tölti be.<br />
    </p>   
    <br />--%>
</asp:content>
```

and i need something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>
<item><title>Már Magyarországon is kapható a Lumia 530 okostelefon</title>


<content:encoded>
    <h1>Már Magyarországon is kapható a Lumia 530 okostelefon</h1>
    <p><b>2014. szeptember 9., Budapest - </b>A Microsoft bejelentette, hogy már elérhető Magyarországon a <a href="http://www.nokia.com/hu-hu/keszulekek/keszulek/lumia530/">Lumia 530</a> belépő szintű okostelefon, amely bevezeti a felhasználókat a Windows Phone világába. A készülék páratlan ár-érték arányú okostelefon-élményt kínál a felsőkategóriás telefonokban is megtalálható, legújabb Microsoft és Lumia innovációkkal és szolgáltatásokkal. A kártyafüggetlen Lumia 530 készülék ára bruttó 34.990 forint.</p>
    <p>Az egy és két SIM kártyás változatban egyaránt kapható, 3G-s Lumia 530 készülék jutányos áron kínálja az legújabb generációs okostelefon-élményt és szélesebb felhasználói réteg számára teszi elérhetővé a Microsoft ökoszisztéma szolgáltatásait. A Windows Phone 8.1 operációs rendszer kimagasló személyre szabhatóságának köszönhetően a Lumia 530 okostelefon a következő előnyöket biztosítja: </p>
</content:encoded></item>
 </rss>
```